# Soap service can't write to XML file

Tags: java, xml, url, serialization, soap

Simple Soap service running on Axis engine on Tomcat v9.0 server needs to read and write to XML files. I developed soap service in Eclipse like a dynamic web project, so the XML files are in the WebContent->WEB-INF->resources->...

When i read the files everything works fine, but when i want to write to the files i get InvocationTargetException. Since i read files normaly, I guess that i'm not opening stream as i should when i write in the files, so can anyone guide me how to do this properly?

Here's the method for reading the file, and this WORKS:

```
public Station deserialization(String name, String path) {
        Station s=null;
        try {
            URL url=getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(path+File.separator+name+".xml");
            InputStream is=url.openStream();
            XMLDecoder decoder = new XMLDecoder(is);
            s=(Station) decoder.readObject();
            decoder.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Main.LOGGER.info("Station deserializaton was not successful!");
        }
        return s;
    }
```

and here's the method for writing into the file, this DOESN'T work:

```
public boolean serialize(Station s, String path) {
        try {
            URL url=getClass().getClassLoader() .getResource(path+File.separator+s.getName()+".xml");
            URLConnection con=url.openConnection();
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream out=con.getOutputStream();
            XMLEncoder encoder = new XMLEncoder(out);
            encoder.writeObject(s);
            encoder.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Main.LOGGER.info("Station serialization was not successful!");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

My real question here is how come the same principle work when reading the file and doesn't work with writing into the file? File paths are the same in both methods.

Comment: Please provide the full stack trace for the error

Comment: You cannot write files into WebContent->WEB-INF->resources-. This becomes a part of zipped war archive containing the application on deployment.

Comment: @ErikKarlstrand I can't, becuse i'm testing soap service with "Web services explorer" in Eclipse, and all i get is InvocationTargetException and i can't catch the exception.

Comment: @Michal Where should i keep the files that Soap service uses while running then?

Comment: I would store them in a database rather then on filesystem. On filesystem every place except under your project shall do. Given that you say you cannot catch the exception I would however think the files location is not the cause of the InvocationTargetException.

Comment: @Michal Unfortunately it's a university project and I'm limited to not use a database in this one. I agree that the file location probably isn't the problem since I read these same files normally. I think I'm not using URL or URLConnection or OutputStream properly, since I'm new to this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community I was asking how to write to xml files trough web service, specifically soap service. And i found solution in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I found what was the problem. Turns out you can read files with URL, but you cant write to URL or URLConnection. I had to use FileOutputStream for writing into the files:

```
XMLEncoder encoder=new XMLEncoder(new FileOutputStream("file_path"));
```

You can also keep the files in WebContent->WEB-INF (if you develop web service in Eclipse) if you want web service to use them, becuse it then makes copies of them.
Just keep an eye on the path that you are providing, double check if it is the right one!